# Python: How to recall position after break from iteration over start, stop, step loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, listiterator

I am learning about iterators and how to use them and in the process have come up with a question. Is it possible to recall where a loop left off during iteration (if the loop were to have a break condition that was met) and then to pick up from the recalled spot?

An example of what I am saying is, I have this code:

```
print("Range() Test")
for i in range(10, 100, 10):
    if i == 60:
        print('Break Point')
        break
    print(i)
for i in range(10, 100, 10):
    print(i)
```

Which should run and give you something like this:

```
Range() Test
10
20
30
40
50
Break Point
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
```

My first question is:

1) Is there a way to recall the position where the break took place and begin from there as opposed to my bumbling start-over? I have seen instanced where the iteration was over a list of items, but have not been able to find an example/work out a functioning example of using iter() on the start/stop/step notation.

2) In doing research (I am learning Python and doing a lot of self-teaching) I have seen the range() function describer both as an iterator and NOT as an iterator so, if anyone has more definitive information on this, as opposed to tearing me a new one for using it in my example, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) not really, that's like saying "if I hang up the phone, can I then continue the phonecall?"  The act of hanging up the phone says "I am not going to continue the phonecall" - if you want to continue it, you don't hang up, you (put the receiver on the table, mute it, put them on hold, something else). Similarly, `break` says "I don't want to continue", and if you do want to continue, don't use break. Call a function, or design so you can `yield`, or something.

Comment: It depends on the usecase. At the very basic level you can save the state of the break point and start from that state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question... I think you are on the right track. The `iter()` will make the range object an iterator. It will track itself and you can pick up where you were later in your code.

```html
>>> x=iter(range(1,100,10))
>>> for i in x:
...     if i >30:
...             break
...
>>> for i in x:
...     print(i)
...
41
51
61
71
81
91
```

2) **range objects are not iterators** [This](http://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/) Does a great job of explaining

Comment: Keep in mind it will be consumed! you can't loop over `x` a second time!

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate all of the feedback on this. Your response was the closest to what I was trying to do and I also appreciate that you added information regarding my question about the range() function.

Answer (score 2):

This is generally bad design.  If you want to pick up where you left off, why are you leaving the security of your loop at all?  You include the irruptive activity in that conditional block.

```
print("Range() Test")
for i in range(10, 100, 10):
    if i == 60:
        print('Break Point')
    print(i)
```

Alternately, save as much of that state as you need to restart:

```
lower = 10
upper = 100
inc = 10

for i in range(lower, upper, inc):
    if i == 60:
        print('Break Point')
        break
    print(i)
old_i = i

for i in range(old_i, upper, inc):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
Range() Test
10
20
30
40
50
Break Point
60
70
80
90
```

~

Comment: Thank you for providing this. It is only slightly different from my starting point and concise. As a beginner in computer programming and with the Python language, is there a particular reason (i.e. memory usage, or similar) that breaking out of a loop and re-entering from the exit of the previous loop would cause that make this bad practice?

Comment: Breaking out of the loop means that you have a second loop trying to do essentially the same thing: double the code, double the local storage, double the set-up time for the `range` object, and double the maintenance.  It also makes your program harder to read and understand, a further hit to long-term quality.